# React js Upload large file size (video or pdf)

Tags: reactjs

When i upload a large pdf size or video it stocked with 0 octet in backend folder, but when i upload a small pdf it's good, the problem in frontend because when i use postman the upload work perfectly :

```
onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    const formData = new FormData()
    formData.append('file' , this.state.cours)
...
}


 onFileChange(e) {
    this.setState({ cours: e.target.files[0] })
}

 <input type="file" onChange={this.onFileChange}  className = "form-control"/>
```

Comment: How large exactly?

Comment: max size 100 mo